# How to run two queries in Node and pass them to the render function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous, promise

I want to run two queries and when they finish pass the data to `res.render`. I've read about promises but I still don't understand how to make the second query pass data and put it in render. Basically I'd like to run the `queryTable` function/promise twice but the second time with `thegraphquery`.

```
app.get('/clickus', function(req, res) {
    var thequery = 'SELECT ab FROM table';
    var thegraphquery = `select cd FROM table `;

    let promise = queryTable(thequery);
    promise.then(
        data => res.render('clickus', {
            'mydata': data
        })
    );
});

function queryTable(thequery) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var con = new msSqlConnecter.msSqlConnecter(config);
        con.connect().then(function() {
            new con.Request(thequery).onComplate(function(count, datas) {
                resolve(datas);
            }).onError(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }).Run();
        }).catch(function(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` to execute both queries simultaneously and wait on both of their results before passing them to `res.render`:

```
app.get('/clickus', function(req, res) {
    var thequery = 'SELECT ab FROM table';
    var thegraphquery = `select cd FROM table `;

    Promise.all([queryTable(thequery), queryTable(thegraphquery)])
        .then(results => {
           res.render('clickus', {
               'queryData': results[0],
               'graphQueryData': results[1]
           });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const createPromise = (time) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(time), time);
});

Promise.all([createPromise(1000), createPromise(2000)])
 .then((result) => console.log(result))
```

**You could use Promise.all api** [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Promise.all accepts an array of promises and the then only fires when all promises resolved. In the then of the Promise.all you accept an array of results for each promise.

```
 app.get('/clickus', function(req, res) {
    var thequery = 'SELECT ab FROM table';
    var thegraphquery = `select cd FROM table `;

    Promise.all([queryTable(thequery), queryTable(thegraphquery)])
     .then(
        data => res.render('clickus', {
                    'mydata': data // an array of data ['thequery result', 'thegraphquery result']
                })
    );

});
```